# Quick question on my notes on Riemann integrability.

Tags: real-analysis

Below is what my professor put as "Aside" and I have no idea what it means.

$$\int_a^b f \bar{g} dx \le \left(\int_a^b |f|^2 dx\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_a^b |g|^2 dx \right)^{1/2}$$

Let $f,g \ge 0$, $f,g \in R$, $fg \in R$ (where R is the set of Riemann integrable functions). $P,T$ partition pair. Then $R(fg, P, T) \le$...

Comment: What is your question? What you're being presented with is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I presume the first integrand should be $|f \overline{g}|$?

Comment: Or, better, $|\int_a^b f \overline{g}|$

Comment: Hmm...my note doesn't have an absolute value. It must be my mistake. Thank you for the reference to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality! I'll take a look at it.